# Regex empty html link

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I'm using notepad++ to do some regex searches throughout my site. What I'm looking to find are empty link tags.

What I want:

```
<a href="somelink.html"></a>   //Match
<a name="someanchor"></a>   //Not match
<a href="somelink.html"><img src="someimage.jpg"></a>   //Not match
```

What I tried to search with regex:

```
<a(.*?)href=(.*?)\"><\/a>
```

I thought "?" made the search ungreedy, but my search picks up img tags as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: where is the opening quote for your href tag in the regexp?

Comment: also true its not greedy but it stil wants to find a match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a(.*?)href=(((?!img).)*?)\"><\/a>
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/33